Apache Pulsar to FileSink using pyflink
I'm reading from a pulsar source, doing some filtering and some transformations and then writing to files. I'm using 2 methods

Write to file using a map function - This provides files with the events in plain text
Write to file using FileSink - The files in this method contain data as byte encoded.

Could someone help me identify what the issue is? I would like to use FileSink instead of the map function because i want the files to roll based on a rolling policy. Any pointers appreciated
def flink_job_test():
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    
    pulsar_topic = PulsarSource\
        .builder() \
        .set_service_url('pulsar://broker:6650') \
        .set_admin_url('http://broker:8080') \
        .set_start_cursor(StartCursor.latest()) \
        .set_unbounded_stop_cursor(StopCursor.never()) \
        .set_deserialization_schema(SimpleStringSchema()) \
        .set_topics('learn_tenant/learn_namespace/learn_persistent_topic_01') \
        .set_subscription_name('flink') \
        .set_config('pulsar.source.enableAutoAcknowledgeMessage', True) \
        .set_properties({'pulsar.source.autoCommitCursorInterval': '1000'}) \
        .build()
        

    stream = env.from_source(source=pulsar_topic,
                             watermark_strategy=WatermarkStrategy.for_monotonous_timestamps(),
                             source_name='pulsar_source')

    validated_stream = stream.filter(lambda x: is_valid_json(x, json_schema)).map(add_size)
    validated_stream = validated_stream.map(lambda x: convert_jsonl(x))
    validated_stream.map(lambda x: write_to_file(x))

    output_file_config = OutputFileConfig.builder()\
        .with_part_prefix("test")\
        .with_part_suffix(".jsonl")\
        .build()
    
    rolling_policy = DefaultRollingPolicy.default_rolling_policy(
        part_size=10 * 1024 * 1024,  
        rollover_interval=15 * 60 * 1000, 
        inactivity_interval=5 * 60 * 1000 
    )

      
    file_sink = FileSink\
        .for_row_format('/scratch/', Encoder.simple_string_encoder())\
        .with_output_file_config(output_file_config) \
        .with_rolling_policy(rolling_policy) \
        .build()
    
    validated_stream.sink_to(file_sink)

    env.execute("Test")

For ex, some of the records in the files produced by FileSink are as follows
[B@6c9b6e67
[B@2ba0228
[B@48c32c8f

